# SSL works on apache but not on nginx

Tags: apache-2.2, nginx, ssl, ssl-certificate, https

SSL config on apache

```
SSLEngine On
SSLCertificateFile    /etc/ssl/domain.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/domain.key
```

which works well

Nginx:

```
ssl on; 
ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/domain.crt;
ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/domain.key;
```

`curl` gives:

```
* SSL certificate problem: Invalid certificate chain
* Curl_http_done: called premature == 1
* Closing connection 0
curl: (60) SSL certificate problem: Invalid certificate chain
```

chrome says:

```
net::ERR_CERT_DATE_INVALID
```

Anything wrong with my nginx conf?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the [certificate chain](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/configuring_https_servers.html#chains) to your Nginx certificate. Basically this says "this certificate is issues by that CA, here's the first step how to find and validate this certificate". You haven't given us enough information to help you any more than that - eg your CA.

Type "nginx certificate chain" into Google and you'll get all kinds of tutorials, like [this how-to](https://scottlinux.com/2013/09/02/how-to-configure-ssl-certificate-chain-for-nginx). You probably need to read up on [what a certificate chain is](https://support.dnsimple.com/articles/what-is-ssl-certificate-chain/) as well.

Comment: The interesting part is why did it work on Apache; it shouldn't, as the same intermediate certificates would have been needed by a client. But as it's Apache 2.2, maybe there was a separate `SSLCertificateChainFile` directive not mentioned in the question. That would have been deprecated on current Apache 2.4, and certainly not how you do this with Nginx.

Comment: I don't know much about Apache. My assumption (probably incorrect) is perhaps it can reach out and get the intermediate certificate itself.